# store image in mssql server vb.net

Tags: image, sql-server-2008

Hi I am having a problem storing image to mssql server I tried both Memory stream and BLOB as well and in both scinarios I get the same error "cannot insert the value null into image column msg 515 level 16 state 2 line 1", any suggestion is more than welcome Thanks.

```
             Dim sqlstring = " begin tran;"
             sqlstring &= " INSERT INTO tbl_customers (stnname, cardnum,
             family_name,  city, fam_mem_nu, id_num, mrkz_num) VALUES
             ('" & stn & "','" & cd & "', '" & fmnm & "','" & ct & "', '" 
             & fnum & "', '" & idn & "', '" & cntr & "')"
             sqlstring &= "INSERT INTO tbl_customers(imag) SELECT * FROM  
             OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\temp\tempimg', SINGLE_BLOB) imag ;  "
             sqlstring &= "commit tran;"
             sql.CommandText = sqlstring
             sql.Connection = conn
             conn.Open()
             Dim ms As New MemoryStream

             img = CameraControl1.SnapshotSourceImage   


             img.Save("c:\temp\tempimg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

            'CameraControl1.SnapshotSourceImage.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
            ' PictureBox3.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox3.Image.RawFormat)
             ' ms.ToArray()
            ' Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
            '  Dim p As New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@img", SqlDbType.VarBinary)
            ' p.Value = data
            ' sql.Parameters.Add(p)
            Dim x As Integer = sql.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Comment: You need to use parameterized queries here. Your code is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Is this file location on the sql server or the application server? Also, why are you doing two inserts here? The first one to insert the customer data and another row with nothing but the image?

Comment: Sean I did do parameterized first, but I did it like this as transaction, yes I did it for the image because I cant combine both queries in one, but this is not the problem is it ?, The error I am getting is " you can not insert Null in a column does not accept null, I am trying to solve this problem for 4 days with no success and I have a deadline so I really appreciate any input on this. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what a transaction has to do with not using parameters. Keep in mind that your second insert is trying to insert a row that is all NULL except for the image (hopefully you are using varbinary(max) and not the deprecated image datatype) column. This means you are trying to insert a row with no other data. You don't have to use OPENQUERY to insert binary data. You can do this from the application and pass the binary as a parameter just like all the other data.

Comment: Thanks Sean for the reply, but if you see my code I already tried that and passed it as SQL bin parameter and I had the same problem.

Comment: wow its realy some times I feel no brainer, when I insert the first line it tells it should come up with this error because it inserting the first line. Thanks any way Sean

Comment: You have two insert statements and the error message is clearly telling you that you have at least one column that is not null. Your second insert is the problem. You can't have a row in tbl_customers with only an image. It either needs to be an update or part of the original insert statement.